# How to make the compiler choose the non-template version of a method for derived classes?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, matrix

I'm writing a matrix class (CMatrix), with such derived classes as a 3d vector(CVector) and a rotation matrix(CRotMatrix). My CMatrix object could be multiplied by an another CMatrix-based object or by an any numerical value(scalar).
This code represents the essence of the problem I got:

```
template<class T> class CMatrix
{

public:

    template<class U> const CMatrix& operator=(const CMatrix<U> &inp){return (*this);}

    CMatrix& operator*(const CMatrix &inp) 
    {   
        cout<<"Multiplication by CMatrix"<<endl;
        return (*this);
    }

    template<class U> 
    CMatrix& operator*(const U &inp)
    {
        cout<<"Multiplication by a scalar."<<endl;
        return (*this);
    }

};

template<class T> class CVector: public CMatrix<T>{};
template<class T> class CRotMatrix: public CMatrix<T>{};

int main()
{
    CMatrix<int> foo1;
    CMatrix<int> foo2;
    CVector<int> dfoo1;
    CRotMatrix<int> dfoo2;

    foo1 = foo1*foo2;   //calls CMatrix method
    foo1 = foo1*5;      //calls scalar method
    foo1 = foo1*dfoo2;  //calls scalar method, shoud be CMatrix
    foo1 = dfoo2*dfoo1; //calss scalar method, shoud be CMatrix

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler prefers the template version of operator*(). Is there any way to make the compiler choose the proper method for derived CMatrix classes in this situation? If I cut off this method

```
CMatrix& operator*(const U &inp)
```

The compiler does it in the right way, but the class loses the ability to be multiplied by a scalar. I'm using msvc10. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you have s separate `CRotMatrix` type that derives from  `CMatrix`? It seems unnecessary to me since a rotation matrix can be represented by an ordinary `CMatrix` just fine.

Comment: I did it because I want it possible to init a rotation matrix in such way:

Comment: Then make the initialization code a non-member function. For example, you could write something like `template<typename T> void InitRotMatrix(CMatrix<T>& mat, T roll, T pitch, T yaw) {}`. That way you won't need to have to create a new type and the code will be self-documenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the template operator is considered an exact match while the matrix version requires a conversion to parent reference. Thus the compiler pick the template as a better match.

First consider if you really need the child classes that you've created and that they provide the appropriate functionality/overrides.

If you need them then I would solve the problem by making one or both of the operations *not an operator*. By making `operator*` do both kinds of multiply you violate the principle of least surprise having it do two wildly different things depending on context. I would suggest named methods for both so it's obvious, but otherwise I would suggest `operator*` to be matrix math and a function `ScalarMultiply` to do the single scalar type.

Comment: Thank you! I think I should better do it without inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the compiler prefers the template version of operator*(). Is there any way to make the compiler choose the proper method for derived CMatrix classes in this situation?

That's because you told it to. Your `Multiplication by a scalar` method is more generic than is your `Multiplication by CMatrix` method.

Make your "Multiplication by a scalar" method be what the comment says it is:

```
CMatrix& operator*(const T & inp)
{   
    std::cout<<"Multiplication by a scalar."<<std::endl;
    return (*this);
}
```

**Addendum**
Your `template<class U> CMatrix& operator*(const U &inp)` is so generic that it matches *anything*. Multiple by a `std::istream`: No problem. It prints `Multiplication by a scalar.` You want your multiplication by a scalar to be restrictive, not a catch-all for any random type.

Comment: I've made this method so generic because I wanted my class interact with any numerical types, not only with the actual template type. E.g. Matrix<int>*float. I thought that I would be able to restrict the method inside itself by a conversion the input scalar to the actual matrix type: `matrix(i,j) += (T)inscalar;`. So it will give an error during compilation if the argument has a wrong type. Don't know if it is a good way.

Comment: Like it or not, C++ does automatic type promotion on numeric types. A function expects an `int`, you provide a `float`? No problem. That `float` is automatically converted to an `int`. In other words, `CMatrix& operator*(T inp)` will do exactly what you want, and it is not so overly generic that it matches every type possible.